# error while loading shared libraries: libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5:

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I have installed one code for my research,when I try to run it I got

```
./procmt_main: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

These shared libraries appear to be here,but

```
root@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# ls -lia libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5
ls: cannot access 'libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5': No such file or directory
```

I am trying to remove qt4,but 
sudo apt-get remove qt4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

```
E: Unable to locate package qt4
root@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# ls -lia qt4
total 88
3016807 drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Abr 20 19:10 .
2756528 drwxr-xr-x 109 root root 77824 Jun 24 11:24 ..
3147728 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Abr 20 19:10 bin
3147729 drwxr-xr-x  15 root root  4096 Abr 20 19:12 plugins
root@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# ls -lia qt5
total 100
3016808 drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 Jun 24 11:24 .
2756528 drwxr-xr-x 109 root root 77824 Jun 24 11:24 ..
3147768 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jun 24 11:24 bin
3147769 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Abr 20 19:10 libexec
3020631 drwxr-xr-x  97 root root  4096 Jun 24 11:24 mkspecs
3147770 drwxr-xr-x  16 root root  4096 Abr 20 19:13 plugins
3147771 drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Abr 20 19:12 qml
```

I do not understand these linking issues,why this file does not exist?

Comment: libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5 : If Debian → install / reinstall libqt5xmlpatterns5 .... Or the problem could be your "code"? , if it's a 32bits executable.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Ubuntu 16.04,64 bit.

Comment: »» I am trying to remove qt4 «« : Why ? ... qt4 , qt5 can both be installed. All files have unique names.